# Shows that every subspace $W$ of a finite dimensional vector space $V$ is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology, continuity

A topological isomorphism between two topological vector spaces is an application between the two that is both isomorphism and homeomorphism. If $V$ is a vector $\mathbb K$-space of finite dimension $n$ over a field metric $K$, we will call the Euclidean topology in $V$ to the only topology with respect to which all isomorphisms of $V$ in $\mathbb {K}^n$ are topological.

A metric field is a pair $(K, | |)$, where $K$ is a field and $| |$ is an absolute value in K.
An absolute value in K es any function $||:K\rightarrow R$ , where R is an Archimedean ordered body, which fulfills the following properties:

a) $| x | ≥ 0$ and the only element of $K$ that satisfies $| x | = 0$ is $x = 0$.

b) $| x + y | ≤ | x | + |y|$

c) $| xy | = | x || y |$

"To prove it, we observe that $W$ can be expressed as the kernel of a linear map of $W$ in $\mathbb K^n$, that is, as the anti-image of $0$ by a map it continues and, since $\{0\}$ is closed, its anti-image as well ($\mathbb K$ is a metric field)."

I do not understand this demonstration very well, I would be very grateful if someone can explain it to me better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a subspace $W$ and a subspace $U$ such that $V = U \bigoplus W$.  Consider the projection of centre $W$ and  image $U$ (this is, $f(u + w)= u$. $W$ is the kernel of the projection $f$, which is a continuous map. Therefore $W = f^{-1} ({0})$ so it is closed, since it is the preimage of a closed set by a continuous function.

Comment: A very clear and precise answer. Thank you.